# How to get response (http success/failure code and other variables) on visiting a site

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I know to get a response of a specific url by ajax method by :-

```
$.ajax({
url : myurl.com,
type : GET,
statusCode: {
404: function() {
     alert ('failure');
   }
200: function(){
   alert ('success');
   }
}
});
```

But, in my case when I hit the url, it triggers several other requests (as I see from the 'Network Panel' on Chrome Developer Options). And, I want to get the response of one of those requests generated.
Please tell how to do this. Or is there any method to get responses of all the network requests generated by hitting a url.

Comment: Only via JavaScript it is i think impossible. If you can manage server side of app i recommend to insert status information to output by backend.

Comment: Please explain, what do you mean by "insert status information to output by backend". In my case, I do return the status code for a particular network request. Say, I hit the url : "myurl.com" which automatically requests "url1.php", "url2.php", "url3.php" . Now, the response of "url3.php" is what I need, whereas I don't care about the responses of other requests. And, i've coded the response codes 404 or 200 on the "url3.php"